# Testing a React Native component's function that is using try/catch and calls Image.getSize

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a jest test for the following React Native function that is defined inside a component:

The function gets a data object that has two fields: `url` and `image`, and, based on their values, sets the component's state.

Any suggestion how to test the function when data.image is not null, but a URI of an image? (e.g. `http://a.com/a.png`)

```
getArticleDetails (data) {
  const { url, image } = data

  if (!image) {
    this.setState({ url, image })
  } else {
    try {
      Image.getSize(image, (width, height) => {
        if (width > 2000 || height > 2000) {
          image = null
        }
        this.setState({ url, image })
      }, (error) => {
        image = null
        this.setState({ url, image, title, description })
      })
    } catch (e) {
      image = null
      this.setState({ url, image })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach is to mock `Image.getSize()` and get the callbacks from the arguments passed when it is called.

Here is a simple working example:

---

example.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

export class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }

  getArticleDetails (data) {
    let { url, image } = data

    if (!image) {
      this.setState({ url, image })
    } else {
      try {
        Image.getSize(image, (width, height) => {
          if (width > 2000 || height > 2000) {
            image = null
          }
          this.setState({ url, image })
        }, (error) => {
          image = null
          this.setState({ url, image, title, description });
        })
      } catch (e) {
        image = null
        this.setState({ url, image })
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

---

example.test.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import { Example } from './example';

describe('Example', () => {
  it('should call Image.getSize()', () => {
    // create a mock implementation for Image.getSize()
    const getSizeMock = jest.spyOn(Image, 'getSize');
    getSizeMock.mockImplementation(() => { /* do nothing */ });

    const data = {
      url: 'mocked url',
      image: 'just has to make !image return false'
    }

    const comp = renderer.create(<Example/>).root.instance;
    comp.getArticleDetails(data);

    expect(getSizeMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // get the arguments that Image.getSize() was called with
    // (see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls)
    const getSizeArgs = getSizeMock.mock.calls[0];

    expect(getSizeArgs[0]).toBe(data.image); // first arg should be data.image
    const success = getSizeArgs[1]; // second arg is the success callback
    const error = getSizeArgs[2]; // third arg is the error callback

    // test the success callback with width <= 2000 and height <= 2000
    success(100, 100);
    expect(comp.state.url).toBe(data.url);
    expect(comp.state.image).toBe(data.image);

    // test the success callback with width > 2000 and height > 2000
    success(2001, 2001);
    expect(comp.state.url).toBe(data.url);
    expect(comp.state.image).toBe(null);

    // restore Image.getSize()
    getSizeMock.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks much for the effort! Can you explain the 4 lines starting with expect(mock.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(data.image);? I don't understand them. Why mock.mock? What does calls[0] [0] and [0][1] and [0][2] mean? Why successCallback(100) (100)?

Comment: Sure, `mock.mock.calls` is ["an array containing the call arguments of all calls that have been made to this mock function."](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls).  `mock.mock.calls[0][0]` is the first argument of the first call to the `Image.getSize()` mock which should be `data.image`.  `mock.mock.calls[0][1]` is the second argument of the first call which is the success callback.  `mock.mock.calls[0][2]` is the third argument of the first call which is the error callback.  Once we have access to the callbacks we can call them directly to make sure they work right.

Comment: Impressive. I will test tomorrow, before I mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Yossi no worries.  I changed the variable names and added clarifying comments, hopefully that helps.  Yeah, it's pretty cool what can be done with [mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api)

Comment: Works like a charm. Cool indeed! Thanks much!